# Use Ajax to prevent refresh of page after form submit (Form name unknown)

Tags: html, ajax, refresh, form-submit

I am using the below form and I would like to prevent the whole page from refreshing after an option is selected in the Dropdown-List. Please note it seems I do not have a distinct name of the form. What is the necessary Ajax command and script to do so? I am using Jquery:

> `<script type ="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.8.3.min.js"></script>`

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <div id="select">
    <select name="gebiet1" onchange="this.form.submit()">

<?php
$gebietausgabe = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT Gebiet FROM kernfragen");
while ($row = $gebietausgabe->fetch_assoc())
{

  echo '<option value="' . $row['Gebiet'] . '">' . $row['Gebiet'] . '</option>';
}

?>

    </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you prevent the page from reloading by `preventDefault()`, then you will send a post request to the server and receive your result in the `done` function. If anything goes wrong, the `fail` function will be executed. The `always` function will be executed every time you send the request.

```js
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  
  //this will prevent the page from reloading
  event.preventDefault();
  
  //send a post request to the server
  //$(this).serialize() will get all the values within your form
  //in this case it only gets the value of your select tag
  $.post( "test.php", $( this ).serialize())
    .done(function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
      alert( "finished" );
    });
  
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I cannot get it to run as intended. Where does your code need to be put? Within the <form> </form> tags? Moreover: I have all of my code within the same document. What do I replace the "test.php" with?

Comment: Before ending your body tag (`</body>`), first,  add jQuery using `script` tag. Then open another script tag using `<script type="text/javascript">`, type the code I provided, then close the script tag using `</script>`